# Display sum value from controller in view .net core 6

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-6.0

I am new to .net core and I couldn't find how to display sum value from controller in view.
I have code in controller that it will show the item details from item master table and sum of the qty from transactions table as balance qty. But I am stuck to display that sum value in view. May I request your help?

Below is my controller code.

''' var result = _context.ItemMaster.Select(x => x.ItemCode + x.ItemDesc + x.Uom + x.ItemReg + x.Transaction.Select(t => t.BalanceQty).Sum());
return View(await result.ToListAsync());'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ViewBag` to display that sum value in view.

In controller, add :

```
//var result = ...your sum value
  ViewBag.result=result;   
 return View(await result.ToListAsync());
```

In the view:

```
@ViewBag.result
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it showing the whole string. I need to put each value like item code, item desc into table columns.

Comment: You are welcome:) If you need to put each value like item code, item desc into table columns. Read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#strongly-typed-models-and-the-model-directive) to know more. @JewelJJ